# Smartsheet OAuth Client lifespan

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-1.1, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2, smartsheet-java-sdk-v2, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v1

Is it possible to create a public OAuth Client id that never expires in Smartsheet using their simple developer account they provide?
They provide trial accounts, but my concern is what happens with the OAuth client when the account expires? Will the client expire to?

Answer (score 0):

Developer accounts are fully featured and can participate in the OAuth flow.

Comment: Hello Steve, thanks for the reply. As far as I understood, the developer account is created out of the trial account. Do you mean the developer account continues to be active after the trial account expires?

Answer (score 0):

The account would need to remain active for the client id to continue working. Trial accounts are just that - trials, so naturally you wouldn't want to setup anything permanent with an account you don't intend to keep.

You might be confusing client ids (essentially an identifier for your app) with access tokens? The client id would remain the same for the life of your app. Access tokens would need to be refreshed periodically. [See the documentation](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#oauth-flow) for details.